# Limit year value to be only 4 digits long

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to restrict user input to 4 digits when entering year in the date field. At the moment it goes up to 6 for some reason. Here's my attempt to limit it, which has miserably failed. Does anyone know why this is?

```
<input
    name="endDate"
    placeholder="End date"
    maxlength="4"
    pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}"
    value={ this.props.values.endDate }
    min={ this.props.values.startDate }
    onChange={ this.update }
    type="date">
</input>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to set the `max` attribute to the last date with a four digit year: December 31, 9999.

Example:

```
<input
    name="endDate"
    placeholder="End date"
    maxlength="4"
    pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}"
    value={ this.props.values.endDate }
    min={ this.props.values.startDate }
    max={ "9999-12-31" }
    onChange={ this.update }
    type="date">
</input>
```

Alternatively, you can just add a check using JavaScript in your `this.update` method that checks that the year contains fewer than four digits.

Comment: Worth noticing is that `min` and `max` attributes are not supported in iOS Safari (https://caniuse.com/input-datetime), at least in iOS 15 and earlier.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input
    name="endDate"
    placeholder="End date"
    maxlength="4"
    max="9999"
    pattern="[0-9]{4}"
    value={ this.props.values.endDate }
    min={ this.props.values.startDate }
    onChange={ this.update }
    type="date">
</input>
```

Try use pattern with [0-9]{4}, and set max for 9999